# Should tfidf be generated with train and test sets combined?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, tf-idf

https://medium.com/machine-learning-intuition/document-classification-part-3-detection-algorithm-support-vector-machines-gradient-descent-282316b0838e

In the above example, tfidf is generated separately for train and test corpus. Shouldn't it be generated together as idf will not be the same when train and test are processed sepratedly vs when they are processed together? Thanks.

```
# Vectorize the training data
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_corpus)

# Vectorize the testing data
X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_corpus)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the test for creating the TF-IDF model, because you are not allowed to assume anything about the test set.

Nonetheless, you still need a way to represent the words in the test set as numbers. That is why you have to train on train set (`vectorizer.fit_transform(train_corpus)`) but only transform (without training) the test set (`vectorizer.transform(test_corpus)`).

Comment: So if the purpose is to determine what would be the best parameter to train on both these two sets to make predictions on unseen data, the two sets still should be separately used as in the example? Thanks.

Comment: Also, what if I have a set of data which contains labeled data and unlabeled data. The purpose is to make predictions on unlabeled data using labeled data. It seems that there should be no problem to craete tfidf using both labeled and unlabeled data.,  the tfidf can then be splited into training and test to learn the best parameters for SVM classification.